# the currency symbol I have chosen does not appear on the screen

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

Xml code is here:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="€0"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

java Code:

```
//This method displays the given price on the screen.
private void displayPrice(int number) {
    TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
    priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
}
```

When I click the button, `sterlin` symbol is appear instead of `euro` symbol. I think is linked "Number Format", but I don't know exactly.

Could you help me? I attached screen shot from my phone.

I try to learn android app developing,
Thanks

when I click the button , I see this screen:

[image: when I click the button , I see this screen]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("da", "DK"));

numberFormat.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("EUR")); 
String currencyString = numberFormat.format(number);

priceTextView.setText (currencyString);
```